# Play h265 videos in Firefox and/or Chromium in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: firefox, video, chromium, html5, hevc

Is there any way I can play h265 videos (with the HTML5 video player) in Firefox and/or Chromium in Ubuntu 20.04?

I know the browsers themselves do not support this codec, but, if I understand it well, if support is present on the system they may delegate to it.

Still, I searched a lot but could not find a way to do that.

Purpose: trying to get the web interface of my surveillance equipment to show me videos recorded in h265 format (live views and/or recordings).

Comment: If your video player plays x265 videos then you already have the required codec (VLC shouldn't be used for this test because it works with its own set of codecs, it doesn't rely on system-wide installed codecs).

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I am having the same problem.